# Qual a regência do verbo "responder"?

Tags: ortografia, regência, regência-verbal

Em [outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6896), surgiu a discussão sobre a regência do verbo "responder".

Quais as formas corretas das duas frases abaixo, com crase ou sem?

> Certifique-se de **responder a** pergunta.
>
> **Responder à** sua pergunta

Comment: E se fosse "pedido"? Terias dúvidas entre "responder **o** pedido" ou "responder **ao** pedido"?

Comment: Boa, @Jacinto, a primeira ficou clara. Já a segunda tem o pronome no meio, seria "responder **ao** seu pedido" ou "responder **a** seu pedido"?

Comment: Creio que podes dizer das duas maneiras. Depende se dizes "**Seu** pedido foi deferido" ou "**O seu** pedido foi deferido". Creio que no Brasil os dois padrões são correntes, e que a presença da preposição ***a*** não faz diferença. Em Portugal é sempre ***o seu***, exceto em narrativas com sabor arcaizante (porque em autores antigos de encontra simplesmente ***seu***).

Answer (score 2):

No caso dado, **responder *à* pergunta**.

Sobre o assunto, diz o dicionário de Francisco Fernandes (autor brasileiro; citações internas omitidas):

> NOTA: Carlos Góis diz que se pode construir indiferentemente *responder **a** carta* ou ***à** carta*. Mas a leitura dos bons exemplares da língua demonstra que a melhor sintaxe é aquela em que *responder* "rege *acusativo* daquilo que se responde, e *dativo* daquilo ou daquele a que se responde." Vem a pêlo, ainda, transcrever aqui a lição de Cândido Lago sobre a regência deste verbo:
>
> > Convém dizer corretamente — "respondendo ***a**o vosso ofício*", "respondendo ***à** sua carta de*", etc. etc. *Aquilo que a pessoa responde* é que é o objeto direto; mas o *ofício* ou *a carta a* que a pessoa responde é *objeto indireto*; por exemplo:
> >
> > > — Que respondeste tu *ao ofício* do diretor?
> > >       — *Ao ofício* do diretor respondi que o pretendente não estava…
> >
> > Vê-se claramente que o objeto direto de *respondi* é a  *cláusula substantiva* seguinte: "que o pretentedente não estava…"

Pelo menos em Portugal, isto é consensual; acho que pouca gente tem problemas com a regência de *responder*.

Comment: Em Portugal, ***a** pergunta* é pronunciado diferentemente de ***à** pergunta*, o que provavelmente ajuda na escrita.